# How to install Tex Live in Ubuntu? (any version)

Tags: software-installation, texlive

I would like to use Tex Live in Ubuntu, how do I install it? Should I add a PPA or download from the main site?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tex Live is updated in annual basis. The last update was in October 2013 in time for Ubuntu release cycle, so [Saucy includes Tex Live 2013](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive) while Raring includes 2012 version. Just looking for `texlive` package for a basic Tex Live installation or `texlive-full` for install the complete Tex Live distribution should suffice.

You can also download directly from the Tex Live website, but it doesn't have any pros compared to installing from the package manager. There is no point in having both the repository texlive installation and the direct TUG TeX Live installation: they mostly consist of the same files, and installing both with double the disk space needed and may lead to version conflicts. Choose one or the other.

If you want to install Tex Live from the main site you will have to fiddle around with dependencies and is a path that is not recommended for those unexperienced with the whole dependencies management. Packaging TeX Live takes a lot of work, so the latest version is often not packaged. However, the world of TeX changes slowly, so this shouldn't be a problem for most users.

So, in one liners, to install Tex Live:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

For a complete/full Tex Live:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

References:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#TeX_Live
- http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html